# How to format nested JSON to a iterative process format

Tags: python

I have a process tree in nested JSON format and Im trying to turn it into a iterative process dictionary with lists. For example, the nested tree is below:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Operator_8a82e",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Link_e5479",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Operator_b7394",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Link_7f62e",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "Operator_73ea0",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "Link_93a51",
                                                    "children": [
                                                        {
                                                            "name": "Operator_32a07"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Link_59e2c",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Operator_3ca6d"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want it to look like this below. Basically each sub-tree is placed in a iterative list (in the order it appears in the nested JSON.. this is very important).

```
{
  "process_1": [
    {
      "name": "Operator_8a82e"
    },
    {
      "name": "Link_e5479"
    },
    {
      "name": "Operator_b7394"
    }
  ],
  "process_2": [
    {
      "name": "Operator_8a82e"
    },
    {
      "name": "Link_59e2c"
    }
  ]
}
```

My current function almost gets me there. Ill explain why it doesn't fully work below.

```
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x):
        i = 0
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a])
        elif type(x) is list:
            for a in x:
                i += 1
                flatten(a)
        else:
            print(x)

    flatten(y)
    return out
```

This returns the following. However I cant seem to distinguish when another sub tree ends (and a new one starts)

```
test
Operator_8a82e
Link_e5479
Operator_b7394
Link_7f62e
Operator_73ea0
Link_93a51
Operator_32a07
Link_59e2c
Operator_3ca6d
```

So for example, ideally the output looks like:

```
test
Operator_8a82e
Link_e5479
Operator_b7394
Link_7f62e
Operator_73ea0
Link_93a51
Operator_32a07
Operator_8a82e # this is what is missing in my function above 
Link_59e2c
Operator_3ca6d
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: @Tomalak not really... just forgot to add my current function Im working through

Comment: How do you arrive at `process_1` and `process_2`? That's not in your input. Where did `Link_7f62e` (etc.) go in your expected output JSON? How does the expected output look like when e.g. `Operator_73ea0` has more than one child?

Comment: Thats a good question (more than one child). Let me add some more information on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tree formatted graph data. You can load it as a `networkx` graph, then export it again in the desired format. Assuming you have loaded the json as a python dictionary called `data`:

```
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
G = json_graph.tree_graph(data, ident="name")
```

Now let's first find all sink nodes (nodes with no outgoing edges), then find  the simple paths from the defined source:

```
#define source node
source = 'Operator_8a82e'
#get a list of sink nodes
sinks = [node for node in G.nodes if G.out_degree(node) == 0]
#get all simple paths from source to sinks
paths = [list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=source, target=sink)) for sink in sinks]
#get first path since there is only one
paths = [i[0] for i in paths if i]
#create dict
[{f'process_{n+1}': [{'name':i} for i in path]} for n, path in enumerate(paths)]
```

Result:

```
[{'process_1': [{'name': 'Operator_8a82e'},
   {'name': 'Link_e5479'},
   {'name': 'Operator_b7394'},
   {'name': 'Link_7f62e'},
   {'name': 'Operator_73ea0'},
   {'name': 'Link_93a51'},
   {'name': 'Operator_32a07'}]},
 {'process_2': [{'name': 'Operator_8a82e'},
   {'name': 'Link_59e2c'},
   {'name': 'Operator_3ca6d'}]}]
```

Comment: Wow thats pretty cool. Didn't know about that library. Works perfect.